# React Native Multiple versions of React (when using hooks)

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I've gone through the 3 main causes of the infamous [invalid hook call warning](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html), and have determined that I have multiple versions of React in my app. I've confirmed this by this step:

```
// Add this in node_modules/react-dom/index.js
window.React1 = require('react');

// Add this in your component file
require('react-dom');
window.React2 = require('react');
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);
```

Based on my research, I understand that it is probably a dependency I have that is listing `react` as a dependency instead of a peer dependency, and that there are a few ways to solve this problem. However, I don't know how to figure out *which* package it is that is causing the issue.

There are lots of solutions online that are relevant to react (such as adding a webpack alias), but unfortunately are not for react-native. I have (perhaps naively) tried to add an alias with `module-resolver` to `babel.config.js`, but that did not work:

```
plugins: [
     [
          'module-resolver',
          {
              alias: path.resolve('node_modules/react'),
          },
     ],
]
```

Comment: Are you using some sort of a lock file to manage dependencies? In my `yarn.lock` for example I can see all of the different versions of packages that are installed and then can search in my lock file for the package that lists the bad version as a dependency.

Comment: That makes sense, but how do I know which packages I am looking for? How do you identify which dependencies are causing the issue?

Comment: Based on your comment above it sounds like you have two versions of `react`, so there will be two different top-level entries for `react` in your lock file. All of the other packages list which package version they depend on so search for the different version strings to see which packages depend on each version and which is the odd one out causing the problems.

Comment: Assuming that the other top-level react packages listed in yarn.lock would be one after the other, I can only find one listing for react., which is `react@16.13.1`. It's a big file (10000 lines) though, I'm wondering if I missed it. We know it's react, but what should I be looking for? there are over 1000 mentions of react in this file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out after a long while. The issue was having `react-dom` library listed as a dependency. I'd read somewhere to do this to support jest testing, but I suppose that advice was dated.

Nonetheless the error was an obvious red herring, so hoping this can help someone out in the future